# Need help saving values from a checkbox without a form

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Hello I will try an explain myself as clear as possible. I'm trying to add a filter products using multiple checkboxes that the user can click on that will alter the my php mysql query.

I have seen some examples of this online but they just show and hide divs. I would like to take the value of the checkboxes click and insert them in the query dynamically.

So my questions is how could I pass a value from multiple checkboxes with out using a form?

```
<div id="filterContentTitle">Filter Results</div>
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Categories</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='1'  /><label for='categories'>Dishwashers</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='2'  /><label for='categories'>Hoods</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='3'  /><label for='categories'>Microwaves</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='4'  /><label for='categories'>Refrigerators</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='5'  /><label for='categories'>Stoves & Ranges</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='6'  /><label for='categories'>Washers & Dryers</label><br />         </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Brands</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='brand[]' value='GE' /><label for='brand'>GE</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='brand[]' value='Viking' /><label for='brand'>Viking</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='brand[]' value='Whirlpool' /><label for='brand'>Whirlpool</label><br />           </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Refrigerators Type</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='subCategory[]' value='French Door'><label for='subCategory'>French Door</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='subCategory[]' value='Bult-In'><label for='subCategory'>Bult-In</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='subCategory[]' value='Side by Side'><label for='subCategory'>Side by Side</label><br />           </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Refrigerators Capacity</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='20.7 cu ft'><label for='capacity'>20.7 cu ft</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='28.6 cu ft'><label for='capacity'>28.6 cu ft</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='20.4 cu ft'><label for='capacity'>20.4 cu ft</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='24.6 Cu. Ft.'><label for='capacity'>24.6 Cu. Ft.</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='25 cu. ft.'><label for='capacity'>25 cu. ft.</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='capacity[]' value='22.0 Cu. Ft.'><label for='capacity'>22.0 Cu. Ft.</label><br />           </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Condition</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='condition[]' value='New'><label for='condition'>New</label><br />         </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="filterContentResults">
         <div id="filterContentCat">Color</div>
         <input type='checkbox' name='color[]' value='Stainless Steel'><label for='color'>Stainless Steel</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='color[]' value='Black'><label for='color'>Black</label><br /><input type='checkbox' name='color[]' value='Biscuit'><label for='color'>Biscuit</label><br />         </div>
```

Comment: You'll need JavaScript with a side of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is bind into the jQuery [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event on the `input`.

When the inputs are changed, you can then update the query that is being sent (presumably with Ajax) to the PHP script

```
$("input").change(function() {
    updateProductList($(this).attr("id"), $(this).prop("checked"));
});

function updateProductList(field, state) {
    // Do Work
    $.ajax({
        source: "my-url.php?" + field + "=" + state
    });
}
```

Note: the example is simplified, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Richard but I am a complete noob when it comes to jquery and ajax. For some reason I thought this would be easier to implement. Guess i have some reading to do.

Comment: Hi @user3354780 - it isn't too hard, just new if you haven't done it before. I'm sure you'll get it!